# Unix Command to find and replace a string in multiple files under nested directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

I need to find file naming with app.properties and replace the string "username" with "user".

I did achieved that by this

```
find . -type f  -name 'app.properties' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e  's/username/user/g'
```

But i want to see the changes as well in a file as an output of that command , how can i do that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash process substitution can be used as a dry run without creating temp files.

Original file:

```
cat
bird
dog
```

Dry run sed command:

```
diff file <(sed 's/bird/frog/' file)
2c2
< bird
---
> frog
```

Here's a bash script that reads paths from stdin and applies the sed dry run. A sed pattern can be passed as an optional parameter.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pattern=${1:-s/bird/frog/}

while read -r path; do
    echo "$path:"
    diff "$path" <(sed "$pattern" "$path")
    echo
done
```

Example with default pattern:

```
find dir* -type f -name file\* | ./sed-dry-run.sh
```

Output:

```sh
dir1/file1:
2c2
< bird
---
> frog

dir2/file2:
2c2
< bird
---
> frog
4c4
< bird
---
> frog
```

Example with a pattern as an argument:

```
find dir* -type f -name file\* | ./sed-dry-run.sh 's/bird/dinosaur/'
```

Output:

```sh
dir1/file1:
2c2
< bird
---
> dinosaur

dir2/file2:
2c2
< bird
---
> dinosaur
4c4
< bird
---
> dinosaur
```

Comment: how can i use diff in this command. 

find . -type f  -name 'app.properties' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak -e  's/username/user/g'

Comment: I've added a sample script that demos the dry-run with a couple examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed -i '.bak' …` to create a `app.properties.bak` file with the original content, then you can use `diff` to see the differences.

Comment: yeah i just found it and also using option -n also gives chance to preview the changes.

find . -type f  -name 'app.properties' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -n  's/username/user/gp'

Comment: @Learner That's not what `-n` does. It suppresses printing the processed lines (unless they're explicitly printed). In your example, this'll delete all lines that don't contain the `/username/user` substitution. If you use it *without the `-i`*, then it'll only print the substituted lines, but with `-i` it deletes all non-substituted lines from the file. So use `-n` to preview, `-i` to make changes, but not both at once. Oh, and make sure you have a backup; this sort of thing is easy to mess up in hard-to-reverse ways.